# limitedReserveTransferAssets WeightNotComputable error

Tags: xcm, zombienet

I’m running a local network with two parachain using zombienet. When I try to transferAsset from one parachain to another using ReserveAssetTransfers I always get WeightNotComputable error.

zombienet config.toml:

```
[relaychain]
default_command = "./bin/polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]
chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  rpc_port = 30100
  ws_port = 30101
  
  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  rpc_port = 30200
  ws_port = 30201
  
  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "charlie"
  rpc_port = 30300
  ws_port = 30301

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "dave"
  rpc_port = 30400
  ws_port = 30401
  
[[parachains]]
id = 1000
chain = "statemine-local"
add_to_genesis = true
cumulus_based = true

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "parachain-A"
  command = "./bin/polkadot-parachain"
  rpc_port = 40000
  ws_port = 40001
  args = [ "-l=xcm=trace" ]
  
[[parachains]]
id = 2000
add_to_genesis = true
cumulus_based = true
chain = "statemint-local"


  [parachains.collator]
  name = "parachain-B"
  command = "./bin/polkadot-parachain"
  rpc_port = 50000
  ws_port = 50001
  args = [ "-l=xcm=trace" ]
  
[[hrmp_channels]]
  sender = 1000
  recipient = 2000
  max_capacity = 8
  max_message_size = 800
  
[[hrmp_channels]]
  sender = 2000
  recipient = 1000
  max_capacity = 8
  max_message_size = 800
```

I created one asset with id 1 in both parachains:

Parachain A:
[image]

Parachain B:
[image]

I already set asset in parachain A that i want to transfer as is_sufficient:

[image]

Then I minted some assets to transfer:
[image]

Finally, we try the extrinsic to send the asset:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Error in parachain B:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i can see the issue must be related with your local setup: You are configuring both parachains in zombienet (1000/2000) with the Statemine runtime and my guess is that [this Statemine configuration](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/master/parachains/runtimes/assets/statemine/src/xcm_config.rs#L172:L175) might be conflicting.

So before troubleshooting this error i would recommend you to set a different parachain that ideally recognize statemine as a reserve as well. You can try the educational [Trappist parachain](https://github.com/paritytech/trappist) for this purpose. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfxU3hUprKo&t=499s) might help you as well.

Also: Based on your screenshot i noted that you are actually sending 5000 Units and not 5000 xUSD (five thousand XUSD) as i think you are trying to send.

Supposing your token is set with 10 decimals, for sending actual 5000 xUSD, the value in the Fungible field should be: 50000000000000.

Comment: It worked. Thak you a lot